# extracting a substring from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  pandas dataframe:

```
#CHROM  POS     INFO
chr1    111    AC=0;AN=33
chr1    111    AC=0;AN=100
chr1    111    AC=110;AN=51
chr2    737    AC=99;AN=10003
chr2    888    AC=100;AN=1636
```

I want to create a new column which is based on the numbers in **INFO** column. That is I want the numbers specified as **AC=N**. So the output should look like

```
#CHROM  POS     INFO            number
chr1    111    AC=0;AN=33.        0
chr1    111    AC=0;AN=100        0
chr1    111    AC=110;AN=51       110
chr2    737    AC=99;AN=10003.    99
chr2    888    AC=100;AN=1636.    100
```

Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Pandas supports a search with regular expressions, see the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that AC is first field, you can do

```py
df['number'] = df.INFO.str.split(';').str[0].str.split('=').str[1].astype('int')
```

Or, with regex, indepentendly of position

```py
df['number'] = df.INFO.str.findall(r'AC=(\d+)').str[0].astype(int)
```

EDIT: rather than findall, we can

```py
df['number'] = df.INFO.str.extract(r'AC=(\d+)').astype(int)
```

It spares the `.str[0]` part. And so is the fastest so far (402 μs per run, vs 556 μs for my previous one, and 563 μs for Kim's version.

Answer (score 1):

use following code:

```
df['INFO'].str.split(r'[=;]').str.get(1)
```

output:

```
0      0
1      0
2    110
3     99
4    100
Name: INFO, dtype: object
```